# drop columns are weekends day. select column that index that are week day only

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas and I need to select the columns with data that represent only weekday and skip weekends, from this .

```
Employee  Thu 02-08 Fri 02-08 Sat 02-09 Sun 02-10 Mon 02-11 Tue 02-12
Daniel,s | 7.65    | 0.00    |0.00     |0.00     |8.45     |8.20
Doucore,d| 5.21    | 8.20    |5.00     |0.00     |8.10     |9.22
Jimene,c | 6.55    | 9.30    |0.00     |0.00     |9.20     |2.00
```

to this:

```
Employee  Thu 02-08 Fri 02-08 Mon 02-11 Tue 02-12    
Daniel,s | 7.65    | 0.00    |8.45     |8.20
Doucore,d| 5.21    | 8.20    |8.10     |9.22
Jimene,c | 6.55    | 9.30    |9.20     |2.00
```

I need to dynamically drop the columns for the weekend (Saturday and Sunday), in any order that they may be. 
any help is highly appreciated
my base code is like this

```
def analize_data(self):

    def check_for_absent_patter(data):
        ''' this will only will check for the last 3 days if there are absent '''
        return True if data[-1]== 0 and data[-2] == 0 and data[-3] == 0 else False

    filtered_data = self.raw_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'Employee ID', 'Title', 'Total Hours', 'Hourly Rate', 'Total Pay'], axis=1)

    ### drop columns around here maybe....

    ready_to_analisis = filtered_data.groupby('Employee').sum()
    ready_to_analisis['long_Absent'] = ready_to_analisis.apply(check_for_absent_patter, axis=1)
    print(ready_to_analisis[ready_to_analisis['long_Absent']].to_string())
```

i know i have to make the drop of the columns after the filtered data first shows. 
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter columns not starting with your strings in tuple by [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith(('Sat','Sun'))]
```

Comment: This is a better/tidier solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
df =pd.DataFrame(columns= ["Thu 02-08", "Fri 02-08", "Sat 02-09", "Sun 02-10", "Mon 02-11" ,"Tue 02-12"],
                data = np.random.rand(3,6))

# this is how you would select columns that dont contain Sat or Sun
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if ('Sat' not in x) & ('Sun' not in x)]]
```